# Export Excel might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I've been created function to export excel this code work in another module

```
$filename='tajima_sparepart_'.date('Y-m-d_H-i').'.xlsx';
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

but when do export, it's show me :

**output might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.**

anyone have solution ?

Comment: What XLS library are you using? PHPExcel? Did you integrate PHPExcel to your Codeigniter project? are you loading the excel library on your method? Are you writing data to the XLS file before exporting them? Did you switch servers or just refactored the code?

Comment: yeah it's PHPExcel, it's already solved by the way ... i forgot to `$this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');` ...

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to load IOFactory class

`$this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');`